# Distribute N items in K sets with minimum overlap

Tags: combinatorics, optimization

I am working on an optimization problem to distribute N distinct items (each of the items is available in infinite quantity), among K sets. Each set should have T items. (The constraint of T can be relaxed as atleast T and atmost T+d)
Objective function is to minimize the sum of pairwise overlap between the sets.

My first approach was to model this as Integer/Linear Programming, but I am unable to model the set overlap constraint.

Could some one please suggest how to approach this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Are you minimizing the sum of pairwise overlaps? Or are you minimizing the largest overlap?  I guess my question is, how are you measuring this 'overlap' quantity that is to be minimized?

Comment: I am trying to minimize the sum of pairwise overlap. Will update the question.

Answer (score 0):

I am wondering about a greedy algorithm where we 'deal out' items to sets one at a time.  So set 1 gets an item, then set 2 gets an item, and so on.  At each step we choose the least used item that can go into the set (we have to avoid putting the same item into a set more than once, unless we are allowed to go to multisets).  Any time we put an item in a set that is in $t$ other sets already, our overlap sum increases by $t$, but with this algorithm, at least at each step, you are minimizing the additional overlap at that step.